# How to change the job state from Scheduled into Running state in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration, job-scheduling

I create one PL/SQL code which is compiled successfully then after I enable this job and then after run this job. But when i see then i found this job is in `scheduled`  state but I want it to be as `Running` state.
`select job_name, state from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = '<job_name>';` So I got it like

```
Job_Name      State
ABC           SCHEDULED
```

How to convert it to RUNNING state. Please help me.

Comment: please enter your pl sql code here

Comment: It is in scheduled state because your run is completed and is waiting for next run. If you want to run a job manually again, you do `dbms_scheduler.run_job('yourjobname')`

Comment: @KaushikNayak After run the above query I got the status as `SCHEDULED`. but the job has been run and also mention in the log. According to the code time interval is start from 10PM daily so at that time job has been run successfully then the state changed to `scheduled`. So is there any chance to convert state to `Running`.

Comment: @user8487380 Are you asking for the job to run continuously? Are you trying to run this on demand? The scheduler works as follows: You schedule a job to run, its state is `scheduled`. At the scheduled time, the job runs and its state is `running`. Upon completion, it returns to `scheduled` until the next scheduled execution time.

Answer (score -1):

this will work:

```
 create or replace procedure enable_job(jobname in) is
 begin
 update table dba_scheduler_jobs set State='Running' where job_name =trim(jobname);
 end;
 /
```

Comment: `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS` is part of data dictionary and shouldn't ever be modified even If you can. I'm quoting from the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datadict.htm#CNCPT1209) *"No Oracle Database user should ever alter (UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT) any rows or schema objects contained in the SYS schema, because such activity can compromise data integrity.Altering or manipulating the data in data dictionary tables can permanently and detrimentally affect the operation of a database."*

Comment: As @KaushikNayak said, this is bad. **Do Not**, repeat **Do Not** do this.